# WordPress Template Directory

Tags: wordpress

How can I get this to work?  Thanks in advance!!!  I think the first echo should work but it doesn't...it prints out the URL in text instead of showing the image...

```
<?php
      if (is_tree(18)) {
         echo '<img src="' . bloginfo('template_directory') . '/img/icon-trans.png" />';
      } else if (is_tree(20)) {
          echo "<img src='/~cecmsite/wp-content/themes/commonwealth/img/iconIndustrial-trans.png' />";
      } else if (is_tree(22)) {
          echo "<img src='/~cecmsite/wp-content/themes/commonwealth/img/iconInstitutional-trans.png' />";
      } else if (is_tree(24)) {
          echo "<img src='/~cecmsite/wp-content/themes/commonwealth/img/iconComm-trans.png' />";
      } else if (is_tree(27)) {
          echo "<img src='/~cecmsite/wp-content/themes/commonwealth/img/iconService-trans.png' />";
      } else if (is_tree(39)) {
          echo "<img src='/~cecmsite/wp-content/themes/commonwealth/img/iconTraffic-trans.png' />";
      } else {
      echo "";
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: Are you already in a PHP block, or not???

Comment: Yes I am.  Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using bloginfo('template_directory') use get_bloginfo('template_directory')

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't open another PHP block, as that will break your code.

Use concatenation instead:

```
echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/img/icon-trans.png" />';
```

Comment: I updated my original post to show what I'm trying to do.  Thank so much for your help so far!!!